# Visual Studio says Unrestricted Nuget says AllSigned?? (Powershell Host)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

So I am flabbergasted by this problem.

I am trying to add Entity Framework to a blank Console Solution via Nuget at my workplace. I have full Admin Rights and I run Visual Studio Professional 2013. It's the 7.0 version of Entity Framework.

When I do so, I get the following message:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. **If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned**, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.

I open up my Package Manager Console and I see the following:

> Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  **Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of Unrestricted**. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".

So I went on the mighty internet and found steps where I open up the x32 and x64 bit version of Powershell respectively and use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to set the Policy as `Unrestricted`. Then I restart Visual Studio and try again. It keeps happening.

Anyone knows what I need to do?

Comment: What *do* you see when you perform `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`?  Please edit that into the question, right after the block quote that asks you to check it.  *(PS - I bet there's a hint in there somehwere as to the issue)*

Comment: I figured it out. Visual Studio was missing a hotfix that made the newest version of Nuget actually work as intended.